# Smooth KeyPress event

Tags: javascript, events

I have a noob question, I searched over the internet but didn't find something similar.

I have an array which contain all key pressed.

I would like to increment the value for each frame my key as been pressed.

```
key = []
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){window.onKeyDown(e);})
window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){window.onKeyUp(e);})


window.onKeyDown=function(e)
{
  if(this.key[e.keyCode] == undefined)
  {
    this.key[e.keyCode] = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ++this.key[e.keyCode];
  }
};

window.onKeyUp=function(e)
    {
        this.key[e.keyCode] = undefined;
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j5sae6u/

The problem is the 1 repeat himself many times, before incrementing.

I don't remember how to fix this.

Can you help me? :3

Comment: During your `show` function, you could have it increment each value of `key` if it has a value rather than doing the increment in `onKeyDown`. `onKeyDown` would set it to `1` and `onKeyUp` would set it to `undefined` with `show` doing the actual incrementing.

Comment: This is a solution but I would like to not use loop function if possible, and be the closest possible to the code of the fiddle. 

OFC, if that's the only way, i will do that.